# Popup Error in IE8

Tags: php, internet-explorer-8

Hi this is my fisrt question hope is not a repost, I've searched but didn't find anything, I have a button that calls a popup file and it runs well in Chrome but it doesn't in IE8,
the error it returns is " Invalid argument." 
in this line:

```
function searchBox() {
    newwindow=window.open('searchEmp.php','Search Employee','height=500,width=600');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
}
```

and here is the extract where i call the popup:

```
$employeeSelect='<input readonly="readonly" value"search" id="ssoreadonly" name="sso1"><input type="button" id="search" onClick="return searchBox()" value="Search" />';
```

hope somebody can help me thanks!

Comment: the window name should probably NOT have a space in it. that name is for internal identification only. it's not intended to be visible to the end user. try `Search_Employee` instead.